# Scrape specific list-elements from HTML page

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I am scraping data from a smartphone's product-page displayed on an e-commerce website.

URL: https://www.flipkart.com/

Product:  `Oneplus Nord Phone`

#### What I tried

I tried to select the value next to the "Color" label by the respective attribute `class=_21lJbe`, but it returns 23 elements.

[image]

How to get only the field next to "Color" label.

#### My Code

In last section commented with "#for scrapping Color Name
" I am not getting the desired result.

1. First I tried with *xpath* using class name and index as `[4]`. That gives blank.
2. Then I tried with using full *xpath*, that is also not working:
   `find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="_21lJbe"]')`

```py
#Lets import all required libraries
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import time
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, 
NoSuchElementException
import requests

time.sleep(2)

#Connecting to the webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(2)

url='https://www.flipkart.com/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

#closing login window
login=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_2KpZ6l _2doB4z"]')
login.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Finding web element for search bar
search_field=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="_3704LK"]')

search_field.send_keys('Oneplus Nord Phone')
time.sleep(1)

#Finding web element for search button
search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="L0Z3Pu"]')

#Clicking search button
search_btn.click()
time.sleep(1)

# Creating empty list
urls=[]
Brand_Name=[]
Color=[]
RAM=[]
Display_Size=[]
Battery_Capacity=[]
Price=[]
time.sleep(2)

#scraping urls from page
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="_1fQZEK"]')
for i in link:
    urls.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
time.sleep(4)

for i in urls:
    driver.get(i)
    time.sleep(1)

#for scrapping Brand Name
    try:
        brand=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="B_NuCI"]')
        Brand_Name.append(brand.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Brand_Name.append('-')

for i in urls:
    driver.get(i)
    time.sleep(1)

#for scrapping Color Name
    try:
        clr=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="_21lJbe"]')
        Color.append(clr.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Color.append('-')
```

Comment: Anyone any thoughts onto this ?

Comment: I used clr=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Color")]') to get element for parent which contains both attributes ("Color" heading and its corresponding value, for example "Blue Haze"

Answer (score 0):

#### Find the URL to the product page

As soon as you have the URL of the product-detail page, open it in your browser.

For example search for product `Oneplus Nord Phone` and click on the desired product in the result to open the details page.

#### Use the inspector to copy the element as XPATH

In your browser use the Inspector of Developer Tools:

1. right-click on the desired table row with "Color" to open the context-menu
2. from the context-menu: choose "Inspect element" or similar
3. the source-code will open in a tab, with the inspected HTML selected
4. right-click and select "Copy" or "Copy as", then "XPath"

I got: `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]`

#### Implement the scraping

Using modules `requests` (`pip install requests`) for downloading webpages and `lxml`, Python's  XML-parser.

```py
import requests
from lxml import etree

# product details page after clicking on desired search result
product_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/oneplus-nord-ce-2-lite-5g-black-dusk-128-gb/p/itm7acae55b999e6?pid=MOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH&lid=LSTMOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH49UKTF&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=+Oneplus+Nord+Phone&store=tyy%2F4io&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&otracker1=search&fm=organic&iid=fb6ab285-05b7-4ee1-814f-2159e60033bb.MOBGDWF8GJTFAXVH.SEARCH&ppt=hp&ppn=homepage&ssid=2ahvxwfbefwlnocg1653156108518&qH=656255e2a939106a'

# inspect element of label 'Color', in inspecors source-code, click Copy XPATH or Copy CSS selector
xpath_to_color_label = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]'
xpath_to_color = '//tbody/tr[4]/td'  # simplified from above, and to both cells: label and value

html = requests.get(product_url).content
# print(html)
dom = etree.HTML(html)
color = dom.xpath( xpath_to_color ) # returns both cells as 2 <TD> elements
# <td class="_1hKmbr col col-3-12">Color</td><td class="URwL2w col col-9-12"><ul><li class="_21lJbe">Black Dusk</li></ul></td>
label_text = color[0].text
# To collect the inner text of an element, see itertext(), for example 
value_text = "".join(color[1].itertext())  # to get all inner text
print(label_text, ':', value_text)
```

Prints:

```
Color : Black Dusk
```